# Parsing/Converting XML stock data and uploading to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

This may not be the best way to do it, so I am open to opinions, but I want to pull data from my brokerage through their API and load it into mySQL database. I have php code that I developed to connect and retrieve XML data. Any coding assistance or guidance is greatly appreciated!

What I want it to do:
1. Be able to capture XML data as a variable
2. Parse and upload XML data to mySQL table with the same field names (database and table already created).

Background:
1. I am new to PHP, but know html pretty well and learn fast.

2. I run a php file that retrieves data from my brokerage. I want to be able to:
   (a) capture an XML field as a variable (so that I can create tables based on individual values) and (b) upload XML data into tables

I have read a lot of the threads on the forum and I am struggling to get something to work for me that's close.

sample (obviously it's a lot longer) xml data returned from php data request (tkdataex.php):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response id="e4985128-a402-4334-9e25-b86d930e9703"><elapsedtime>0</elapsedtime>
<quotes>
  <quote>
    <issue_desc>CALL MAR-02 $1550.00</issue_desc>
    <last>0.0</last>
    <volume>0</volume>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <issue_desc>CALL MAR-02 $1575.00</issue_desc>
    <last>0.0</last>
    <volume>0</volume>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <issue_desc>CALL MAR-02 $1600.00</issue_desc>
    <last>0.0</last>
    <volume>0</volume>
  </quote>
</quotes><error>Success</error></response>
```

my code so far (filloptionstable.php) returns server error:

```
<?php

$url = "tkdataex.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    //get url contents

$data = curl_exec ($ch);    //execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

require_once 'dbconnect.php';
$database = 'SPX';
$table = 'SPXchain';


foreach ($xml -> quote as $row){
    $strikeprice = $row -> strikeprice;
    $last = $row -> last;
    $strikeprice = $row -> volume;
    INSERT INTO chain (strikeprice, last, volume) VALUES ($stripeprice,$last,$volume);
}

?>
```

I know that this works for ONE entry manually specifying values, but I cannot figure out how to grab the XML values to make this dynamic (filloptionstablebasic.php):

```
<?php

$url = "testfull.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    //get url contents

$data = curl_exec ($ch);    //execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

require_once 'dbconnect.php';
$database = 'SPX';
$table = 'SPXchain';

$xdate = 20160302;
$strikeprice = 1900 ;
$delta = 0.082;
$interest = 100;
$volume = 120;
$put_call = '"call"';
$bid = 4.56;
$ask = 4.90;
$last = 4.72;
$daychange = -0.24;
$pull_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO SPXchain '.
      '(
        xdate,
        strikeprice, 
        delta,
        interest,
        volume,
        put_call,
        bid,
        ask,
        last,
        daychange,
        pull_time) '.
      'VALUES ( ' .
        $xdate . ', ' .
        $strikeprice . ', ' . 
        $delta . ', ' . 
        $interest . ', ' . 
        $volume . ', ' . 
        $put_call . ', ' .
        $bid . ', ' . 
        $ask . ', ' . 
        $last . ', ' .
        $daychange . ', ' . 
        $pull_time . ')';

mysql_select_db('SPX');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

echo "Entered data successfully into " . $table;
```

Comment: No wonder you have a server error. `INSERT INTO chain (strikeprice, last, volume) VALUES ($stripeprice,$last,$volume)` is SQL.. not PHP. You should start by looking at the PHP manual about mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. Read about prepared statements while you're at it...

Comment: INSERT INTO chain can be used in php. I just updated my first post with "filloptionstablebasic.php" which works fine, but manually specifies values. I cannot figure out how to grab the XML values dynamically.

Comment: I think your direction with mysqli is great! I am reading and simplifying my db connect code and a lot of other items. What I am still struggling to find is resources on how to grab the XML fields to store to variables or push to db table. This site is an excellent resource for anyone starting out with mysqli: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Comment: Unless you have some unofficial PHP-parser, you can't write `INSERT INTO...` straight in the PHP file. You need to do as you did in the second file. Btw... don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. They are both insecure and, as mentioned, deprecated.

Comment: I've added an answer regarding storing XML-properties in variables.

Answer (score 0):

It can be confusing working with `simplexml_load_string()` at first.
The function returns an object where all properties are objects as well.

To be able to store a property value in a variable, you need to cast the property as the correct type.

Change your code to (assuming these values are integers):

```
foreach ($xml->quote as $row){
    $strikeprice = (int) $row->strikeprice;
    $last = (int) $row->last;
    $strikeprice = (int) $row->volume;
    ...
}
```

Use `(int)` for integers and `(string)` for strings.

*PS. Don't have spaces around `->`. That just makes it harder to read.*

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I figured out that the response I was trying to paste was already parsed. Your example is helping me in figuring out how to insert data into tables. I am also following prepared statements now.

Comment: Can I asked you, do you have any experience with curl_multi in php? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789132/php-multiple-simultaneous-data-requests