# PHP Multiple Simultaneous Data Requests

Tags: php

I am trying to get multiple data requests at once to speed up processing time. I have been able to get all of the data I need by looping requests one at a time, but it takes 30-60 seconds. I just discovered curl_multi, but I cannot get it to return data, and so in the new code below, I am trying to get 3 URLs to work, but it'll end up being probably 10+ requests at once. I edited out my keys and replaced them with xxxx, so I already know that it won't run as is, if you try.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Code that works for all requests, but is time consuming:

```
define(TIME, date('U')+3852);

require_once 'OAuth.php';

$consumer_key        = 'xxxx';
$consumer_secret     = 'xxxx';
$access_token        = 'xxxx';
$access_secret       = 'xxxx';

$i=0;
foreach ($expirations as $row){
    $expiry_date = $expirations[$i];

    $url = "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/options/search.xml?symbol=SPX&query=xdate-eq%3A$expiry_date";

    //Option Expirations
    //$url = 'https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/options/expirations.xml?symbol=SPX';

    //Account data
    //$url = 'https://api.tradeking.com/v1/accounts';

    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key,$consumer_secret);

    $access = new OAuthToken($access_token,$access_secret);

    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $access, 'GET', $url);  

    $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, $access);

    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($request->to_header())); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //Turn XML ($response) into an array ($array)
    $array=json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)),true);

    //Trim excess fields from ($array) and define as ($chain) 
    $chain = $array['quotes']['quote'];

    $bigarray[$i] = $chain;
    $i++;
}
```

Returns a huge array as variable $bigarray

Code that isn't working for three simultaneous requests:

```
define(TIME, date('U')+3852);

require_once 'OAuth.php';

$consumer_key        = 'xxxx';
$consumer_secret     = 'xxxx';
$access_token        = 'xxxx';
$access_secret       = 'xxxx';

$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key,$consumer_secret);
$access = new OAuthToken($access_token,$access_secret);

// Run the parallel get and print the total time
$s = microtime(true);
// Define the URLs
$urls = array(
  "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/options/search.xml?symbol=SPX&query=xdate-eq%3A$20160311",
  "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/options/search.xml?symbol=SPX&query=xdate-eq%3A$20160318",
  "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/options/search.xml?symbol=SPX&query=xdate-eq%3A$20160325"
);
$pg = new ParallelGet($urls);
print "<br />Total time: ".round(microtime(true) - $s, 4)." seconds";

// Class to run parallel GET requests and return the transfer
class ParallelGet
{
  function __construct($urls)
  {
    // Create get requests for each URL
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {

      $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $access, 'GET', $url);  
      $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, $access);

      $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($request->to_header())); 
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
    }

    // Start performing the request
    do {
        $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
    } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    // Loop and continue processing the request
    while ($runningHandles && $execReturnValue == CURLM_OK) {
      // Wait forever for network
      $numberReady = curl_multi_select($mh);
      if ($numberReady != -1) {
        // Pull in any new data, or at least handle timeouts
        do {
          $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
        } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
      }
    }

    // Check for any errors
    if ($execReturnValue != CURLM_OK) {
      trigger_error("Curl multi read error $execReturnValue\n", E_USER_WARNING);
    }

    // Extract the content
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      // Check for errors
      $curlError = curl_error($ch[$i]);
      if($curlError == "") {
        $res[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
      } else {
        print "Curl error on handle $i: $curlError\n";
      }
      // Remove and close the handle
      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
      curl_close($ch[$i]);
    }
    // Clean up the curl_multi handle
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    // Print the response data
    print_r($res);
  }

}
?>
```

Returns:
    Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) 
    Total time: 0.4572 seconds

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm still looking for assistance. This is the one portion of my code taking the longest.